# May I ask about feasibility of the following circuit?

Tags: battery-charging, rectifier

Generally, I learned about one diode rectifier and bridge diode (4 diodes) rectifier for making DC signal. Both outputs' maximal value is maximal positive value of input source (using ideal diode). However, if I construct the following circuit, we can get doubled maximal positive DC voltage. May the following circuit operate well?

[image: diagram]

Comment: A question that can be answered by a simple simulation. [Nice](http://tinyurl.com/y88yrzgh).

Comment: Though I wouldn't just feed that straight into the battery. That's just asking for problems and or a destroyed battery. And why do you have two bleeding resistors?

Comment: How do you ensure that GND is connected to *neutral* instead of *live*?

Comment: @HarrySvensson Thank you for comments first. I want to draw higher voltage output utilizing negative voltage part. and I do not understand your second comment. You mean the circuit above will destroy the battery?

Comment: @SimonRichter GND is omitted. It must be located under source part.

Comment: Right now it looks like you are attempting to charge a battery by simply forcing a voltage across its terminals. I don't know what kind of battery you will be trying to charge, but I would use some kind of controller / charger so the battery's lifespan isn't severely reduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circuit you've drawn is called a voltage doubler. It's somewhat easier to see what's happening if it's drawn according to schematic guidelines, with +ve to the top and -ve to the bottom, and rather like a diode bridge rectifier is usually drawn, like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKrcKU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the swing from the AC source charges the +ve rail and the -ve rail alternately. This means the ripple on the differential voltage is at twice the input frequency, just like a full bridge rectifier, not at the input frequency like a conventional half-wave rectifier.

The circuit, with a minor addition, was widely used back in the bad old days, and has only fairly recently been driven from the market by the twin forces of
a) Power factor legislation for power supply inputs
b) The availability of 'universal input' power supplies

The reason for its popularity is that with the operation of a single pole switch, you could make a rectifier that delivered 340V DC, when driven from either 120v or 240v, as below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa13qB.png)</sup>

With the switch open, the 4 diodes act like a conventional full bridge, and give peak voltage across the outputs.

With the switch closed, D3 and D4 operate as half wave rectifiers into C1 and C2, while D1 and D2 take a holiday, they just sit there blocking. The voltage across the outputs is now 2x input peak voltage.

The main technical reason for phasing out this type of supply was its horrible power factor. Once PF legislation began requiring supplies to have PFC inputs, the circuit for doing that could also accommodate operation directly from 120 and 240v supplies without switching. Needless to say, while having the switch open in 120v land meant a temporarily non-working appliance, having it closed in 240v land meant a permanently non-working appliance.

Answer (score 0):

As Harry Svensson has pointed out that this can be easily understood through simple simulation and that's exactly what I will do to answer your question.

Now since you not defined any values of the components I have taken random values with the following points in mind: - The 2 resistors in parallel to capacitors will be as high as possible otherwise they will not produce the peak output. A 5v source of supply and random values to capacitors and diodes.

[image]
[image: Rectifier output]

I believe the simulation answers your question. It's only the last part that you got it wrong. The output is not 
**2*Vinput**
wrt ground, but wrt to the negative voltage at R2.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I also got output voltage like you simulating the circuit using PSpice. However, I want to know its feasibility of obtaining higher voltage source by changing reference point in reality (not theoretical feasibility).

Comment: @GodDanny The battery doesn't know about your _other_ ground, so sure, it's feasible to declare a new _ground_ for another part of the circuit. I mean, I could be a robot talking right now, and you wouldn't care any less, or I could be a human being, or a dog.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwHykn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What is peak current?

What are the risks?

Comment: It looks like the OP was going for a voltage doubler rather than a traditional rectifier setup.

Comment: then he would have to use a clamp diode then a series cap and 2nd clamp diode.   this would only work on half the Vpp input, so that method is useless even if properly constructed.

Comment: I re-arranged answer and schematic into a question